# capture a downloaded pdf file name with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Need to capture the the file name of a PDFs which we get by clicking a download link in a URL. I've tried with this code.but, I cannot get the title or url from the second window
kindly help me out with this or suggest me any other methods to handle this...

```
**code I tried**

@Test

public void pdfname() throws Exception {  
driver.get(baseUrl + "/english/investments/iv_funds.htm");  
Set<String> winids = driver.getWindowHandles();  
Iterator<String> iterate = winids.iterator();  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
driver.findElement(By.linkText("FUND MATERIALS")).click();  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
driver.findElement(By.className("sbToggle")).click();  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Fund Details and Performance Update")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.id("fundPerformance")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.id("fundPerformance")).clear();  
driver.findElement(By.id("fundPerformance")).sendKeys("AEGAU");  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='perform']")).click();  
Thread.sleep(18000);  
winids = driver.getWindowHandles();  
iterate = winids.iterator();  
String firstwindow=iterate.next();  
String secondwindow = iterate.next();  
System.out.println(firstwindow);  
System.out.println(secondwindow);  
driver.switchTo().window(secondwindow); //switch to pdf window  
Thread.sleep(3000);  
System.out.println("url is"+driver.getCurrentUrl());  
driver.close();  
}
```

Comment: what error message are you getting? Are you getting any result by printing first window and second window.

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages instead I'm getting blank output.but, I can print ID of second window

Comment: So you can print firstwindow and secondwindow variables ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the name from a OS system window. Selenium does not interact with the OS. For windows you can use autoit (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to interact with the OS.

Comment: But, the pdf file is opening in chrome browser window(not OS window).

Comment: It looks like that but actually Chrome is opening the OS window.

Comment: Is there any other solution to catch the downloaded file's name in selenium webdriver

Comment: Take a look at the element you are clicking. Maybe the filename is in there and you can get the text without clicking the element just using a element.getText().

Comment: actual scenario is that, I'll be pasting a code inside a textbox in web page and click the download button nearby. at the time a pdf will be downloaded respective to the code entered need to capture the name of that pdf.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that you configure the browser to download files in a default folder automatically and then you browse the folder with Java (not selenium) to get the file name.